# ERROR IPAProxy ipa_proxy.cpp:149 Configuration file 'ov5640.json' not found for IPA module 'raspberrypi'?

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to interface ov5640 with raspberry Pi 4 model B, kernel version 5.15.61,  till now I had loaded driver successfully and Bound driver with ov5640 successfully, and video nodes were created successfully.
I tried to stream video using gstreamer
command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 libcamerasrc ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! clockoverlay time-format="%D %H:%M:%S" ! autovideosink
```

and it thrown error
error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
[0:02:06.704696651] [1320]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3866-0c55e522
[0:02:06.726785010] [1324]  WARN CameraSensor camera_sensor.cpp:212 'ov5640 10-003c': Recommended V4L2 control 0x009a0922 not supported
[0:02:06.726879464] [1324]  WARN CameraSensor camera_sensor.cpp:264 'ov5640 10-003c': The sensor kernel driver needs to be fixed
[0:02:06.726907245] [1324]  WARN CameraSensor camera_sensor.cpp:266 'ov5640 10-003c': See Documentation/sensor_driver_requirements.rst in the libcamera sources for more information
[0:02:06.728038265] [1324]  WARN CameraSensor camera_sensor.cpp:411 'ov5640 10-003c': Failed to retrieve the camera location
[0:02:06.746434072] [1324] ERROR IPAProxy ipa_proxy.cpp:149 Configuration file 'ov5640.json' not found for IPA module 'raspberrypi'
[0:02:06.746582013] [1324] ERROR IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:213 Could not create camera helper for ov5640
[0:02:06.746635055] [1324] ERROR RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1253 Failed to load a suitable IPA library
[0:02:06.746922788] [1324] ERROR RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1184 Failed to register camera ov5640 10-003c: -22
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstLibcameraSrc:libcamerasrc0: Could not find any supported camera on this system.
Additional debug info:
../src/gstreamer/gstlibcamerasrc.cpp(354): gst_libcamera_src_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstLibcameraSrc:libcamerasrc0:
libcamera::CameraMananger::cameras() is empty
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Failed to set pipeline to PAUSED.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

can anyone give me a direction how to solve this?